Am I correctly computing $d(df)$ for a smooth function $f:M\to N$ between manifolds?
Context: a while ago I made a post on how to compute $d(df)$. The accepted answer consists of a hint that allowed me to compute it, yet recently the 'strangeness' of the result makes me wonder if my result is correct, hence this post. $\def\bx{\textbf{x}}$

Setup: Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth function from an $m$- to an $n$-manifold. The charts $(\phi,U)$ of $p\in M$ and $(\psi,V)$ of $f(p)\in N$ can be 'extended' as charts of $TM$ and $TN$ in a natural way:
\begin{align}
\Phi:U\times \mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2m}&:(p,v_p)\longrightarrow \Big(\phi(p),\phi_p(v_p)\Big)\\
\Psi:V\times \mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}&:(q,w_q)\longrightarrow\Big(\psi(q),\psi_q(w_q)\Big)
\end{align}
where $\phi_p$ and $\psi_q$ are defined -thinking of tangent vectors as derivations- by
\begin{align}
\phi_p:T_pM\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^m&:v_p\longrightarrow \Big(v_p(x_1),\ldots,v_p(x_m)\Big)\\
\psi_q:T_qN\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n&:v_q\longrightarrow \Big(v_q(x_1),\ldots,v_q(x_n)\Big)
\end{align}

Result: let $\widehat{f} = \psi\circ f\circ\phi$ and $\widehat{df} = \Psi\circ df\circ \Phi^{-1}$. Using the hint, we get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(\widehat{df})^i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\left(\sum_k x^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\widehat{f}^i\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\widehat{f}^i + \sum_k\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^j\partial x^k}\widehat{f}^i,
$$
so that
$$
\textbf{J}( df)
= \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial \widehat{f}_i}{\partial x_j} & 0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\widehat{f}^i + \sum_k\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^j\partial x^k}\widehat{f}^i & \dfrac{\partial \widehat{f}_i}{\partial x_j}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Is this correct?

Since you're working so much with differential forms and exterior derivatives, maybe it would be better to write $DF$ for the derivative of a mapping $F$ between manifolds, rather than $dF$.
